# how to print a text file until it is matched to a string

Tags: python

how to print a text file until it is matched to a string.

Consider below text file :

```
00:d7:8f:0a:86:5c    ST0123-AP22              Joined             Flexconnect      Manual      No
00:d7:8f:1e:d6:18    ST0123-AP14              Joined             Flexconnect      Manual      No
00:d7:8f:1e:dd:50    ST0123-AP03              Joined             Flexconnect      Manual      No

Efficient AP Image Upgrade ..... Enabled

Group Radius/Local Auth Parameters :
 Radius Retransmit Count......................... 3 (default)
 Active Radius Timeout........................... 5 (default)

Group Radius AP Settings:
AP RADIUS server............ Disabled
EAP-FAST Auth............... Disabled
LEAP Auth................... Disabled
EAP-TLS Auth................ Disabled
EAP-TLS CERT Download....... Disabled
PEAP Auth................... Disabled
```

I want to print the lines upto the string "Efficient AP Image Upgrade ..... Enabled" :
The thing is lines count vary on each output.

I have tried to readlines and ttried a for loop too but couldn't achieve the goal.

Comment: Well show us the code that you tried so we have with what to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
  with open('your_file.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            if line == 'Efficient AP Image Upgrade ..... Enabled\n':
                break
            print(line)
```

Comment: I had the same idea but i tried it and it won't work. Did you try it ?

Comment: No I didn't try it but if the string you provided as the final one is written correctly, it should work. You can add a print(line) after loop starts to see the actual strings and debug further

Comment: to work with this example you have to compare : `line == 'Efficient AP Image Upgrade ..... Enabled\n' `

Comment: Yeah, I know, I wasn't sure tho how the file was written to

Comment: it is not necessary to use `readlines`, just `for line in file`. When looping files you also get the trailing `'\n'`, it is better to use `in` instead of exact comparison

Comment: Edited. Hope it works as you say

Comment: Sorry if my comment was confusing, you removed the `'\n'` so now it probably won't work again. You have two options: either do `line == "<string>\n"` or `<string> in line`

Comment: Now it works.. I tried with  line == "<string>\n" and looks good.
However I'm getting empty space for each line when it iterates the loop.
Probably I need to strip off the empty space.